# Gradient Transparent view swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

im trying to make a gradient transparent view alert as shown in the picture below, any help ?

[image: Screenshot]

```
@IBInspectable var InsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
@IBInspectable var OutsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let colors = [InsideColor.cgColor, OutsideColor.cgColor] as CFArray
    let endRadius = min(frame.width, frame.height) / 2
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: nil)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: endRadius, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsBeforeStartLocation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have it statically in your project assets instead of creating it dynamically every time. So:

1. Create an image with the clear center and black fill color like this:

[image: Gradient]

**Note that** the center part is **NOT** white. It's transparent. So you should see behind it like this example:

[image: Transparet preview]

2. Then add an `imageView` and fill it with this image.
3. Set the `backgroundColor` of the image view to `.clear`
4. done.

**Note**: Don't forget to set the `backgroundColor` of the original view of your custom alert to `.clear` and `modalPresentationStyle` of the custom alert **controller** to `.overCurrentContext`